# How to retain date format while reading the excel file in Python

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, date

Original Column:

```
Date Of Birth
09/01/1990
18/02/1976
08/04/1983
10/02/1973
03/03/1987
02/11/1977
25/05/1992
```

I want to get the exact same date format in python which can later be exported in the same format to excel. I am not allowed to use strftime to change the format, since I need to check if the date present in excel is of the format %d/%m/%Y or not.

I have tried using the following below methods and much more but none seem to work:

Example Try-1:

```
import pandas as pd
df=pd.read_excel('file.xlsx',sheet_name='sheet', dtype= {'Date_Of_Birth': str})
```

Result in Python:

```
Date Of Birth
09/01/1990 00:00:00
18/02/1976 00:00:00
08/04/1983 00:00:00
10/02/1973 00:00:00
03/03/1987 00:00:00
02/11/1977 00:00:00
25/05/1992 00:00:00
```

Example Try-2:

```
import pandas as pd
df_ = pd.read_excel('file.xlsx',sheet_name='sheet',\
                   parse_dates=['Date_Of_Birth'], dtype={'Date_Of_Birth': object})
```

Result in Python:

```
Date Of Birth
1990-01-09
1976-02-18
1983-04-08
1973-02-10
1987-03-03
```

I need python to read exact same format as shown in the top image (excel file). Also this is an excel file with .xlsx format and xlrd is not useful here.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: def check_date_format(date_str):
    import re
    return bool(re.match(r"\d{2}/\d{2}/\d{4}", date_str))

df['IsCorrectFormat'] = df['Date_Of_Birth'].apply(check_date_format)

print(df)

Comment: This I'm already using to check the format. But if some format is wrong then I need to add it to excel (the original one) and suggested fix. Which can only happen if python can take the date as it is.

Comment: Did you try openpyxl

Comment: yes, it produces the same results as above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue is because Excel has automatically recognized them as date objects and applied its own formatting, that's why it is not keeping your desired format when reading the file programmatically.
I read the dates from the Excel file and convert them to the "%d/%m/%Y" format, if they are stored as date objects.

```
import openpyxl
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime

workbook = openpyxl.load_workbook(r'XXX\Test.xlsx')

worksheet = workbook.active

data = []

for row in worksheet.iter_rows(min_row=1, max_col=1, values_only=True):
    cell_value = row[0]
    if isinstance(cell_value, datetime):
        date_as_str = cell_value.strftime("%d/%m/%Y")
    else:
        date_as_str = str(cell_value)
    data.append([date_as_str])

header = [data[0][0]]
data_values = [item[0] for item in data[1:]]

df = pd.DataFrame(data_values, columns=header)

print(df)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks but Not using strftime for a particular format is a condition that needs to be followed. The Excel date can be in other formats also. I just need to fetch it as it is (with any changes or restructuring).

Comment: Oh, not using strftime, you say? Well, grabbing that Excel date without any changes is like teaching a cat to bark – sounds fun, but good luck with that.